# Error message = Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code I am using. Is it happening because the "Changing Cell" is in another worksheet ("Assumptions")?

```
Sub CAPEXoptimization()
'
' CAPEXoptimization Macro
' Optimizes CAPEX by changing DSCR (net of capex and new financings) to 1.0x
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+c
'
    Application.Goto Reference:="CAPEXoptimization"
    
    Range("N21").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("1"), ChangingCell:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“Assumptions”).Range(“N173”)
        
  
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`Range("1")` is the issue here; there is no column.

I recommend you add `Option Explicit` at the top of all of your modules and classes, and then use Debug / Compile to check for early errors in your code. I suspect the double quotes you copied and pasted into your question will not compile.

You can make `Option Explicit` appear automatically by checking Tools / Options / Editor / Require variable declaration.

Comment: I used "1" because my goal in goal seek was to achieve 1. But I have now entered this value in a cell and referenced the cell. Now i get Run time error '9': Script out of range

Comment: The error probably stems from ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Assumptions"). Is there such a worksheet? Have you corrected the double quotes, i.e. “ and ” surrounding Assumption and N173, which should be " ? Did you add Option Explicit and use Debug / Compile?

Comment: You were right. The error was from the double quotes. It worked after i corrected it. Thank you very much :)